# WebGL: Invalid Image when loading 8-bit grayscale image to texture

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to render an 8-bit grayscale JPG downloaded from my server into a texture to render with WebGL.

```
// Pretend for the sake of example that I have passed in an argument 
// 'img' that is an Image object that I used to download the jpg.
// See the EDIT below for how this happens...

// ...also presume that I have set up my WebGL context and assigned it 
// to the variable 'gl':
// const gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');

const texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

// Upload the image into the texture.
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
```

At this point, WebGL slaps me in the face and takes my lunch money:

```
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: invalid image
```

and I am left to ask: WHAT MOAR U WANT WebGL?? WHY NOT U JUST B HAPPY???

I'm probably missing something basic, but the internets are a mess with WebGL stuff that doesn't answer my question. Can any WebGL gurus here advise?

Here is the image:

[image: 8-bit Grayscale JPGs 4LYFE!]

**EDIT:**

Here are some more details about how the image is obtained. *Note: the reason for doing it this way is that I need a download queue that I can shuffle, cancel, and restart, ad nauseam.* Hence the use of fetch, blobs, and object URLs. This whole thing is part of a deep-zoom image viewer that should efficiently load only the image tiles visible in the viewport (which often changes moment to moment). Anyway, here's how I get the image:

```
// Take care of vendor prefixes:
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

// This is where we'll assign our final product
const imageTag = new Image();

imageTag.onerror = (err) => {
  console.error('IMG ERROR:', err);
};
imageTag.onload = () => {
  // Once the image tag has loaded the blob data, clean up our object url:
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(imageTag.src);

  // imageTag is now passed into the code above as 'img'
};

// Grab the image data as a blob
fetch(`<url_of_image>`)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    // When we get the image data, wrap it in an object url and assign
    // it to src. The onload event won't fire until the next tick.
    imageTag.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  });
```

I should point out that I was originally rendering using the canvas2D API, and that it was able to draw the images just fine using the `drawImage()` method. So I'm pretty sure the images objects are loading ok.  My reason for implementing a WebGL renderer is to open the door to greater performance enhancements.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Can you post details of how the texture image is actually obtained? Searching through Chrome codebase for the error message suggest that the problem lies there.

Comment: @KirillDmitrenko Edit added that gives more detail on how the image is obtained.

Comment: Do you waiting for image to be loaded before using 'texImage2D'

Comment: @pleup Yes - I am sure that the image is fully loaded from the server before I call `texImage2D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright party people, I figured this out (one way to do it at least).

The original flow, which I could never get to work, was:

1. *Fetch image data as blob*
2. *Use ObjectURL to be able to pass blob to image tag on `src` attribute*
3. *Pass image tag into `texImage2D` (old method signature)*

The new flow that worked for me is:

1. *Fetch image data as array buffer*
2. *Decode jpg data into Uint8Array using [jpeg-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js)*
3. *Pass Uint8Array into `texImage2D` (new method signature)*

It looks like this:

```
// I am using the decode() method from jpeg-js. Passing true as a second parameter 
// causes the data to be returned wrapped in a Uint8Array. Even though the data
// was one channel going in, it's going to come out with all four (RGBA) channels.

import { decode } from 'jpeg-js';

// Like before, please presume a global gl variable to be my WebGL context.
const gl = '<my-webgl-context-that-I-set-up-elsewhere>';

fetch(`<url_of_image>`)
  .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buffer => {
    // When we get the image data, it's still encoded. We need to decode it
    // before we've got pixel data. We want it as a Uint8Array which will make
    // texImage2D() happy.
    const pixels = decode(buffer, true);

    // Set up a new texture where we'll capture and keep the image data
    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    // Upload the image into the texture:

    // Here we are telling WebGL how many bytes each pixel will be (I think 
    // think the default is 4, but I thought that this step was important to show).
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

    // jpeg-js is kind enough to provide the dimensions of the image data in its
    // returned value. Since jpeg-js returns the data with all 4 channels, we use
    // gl.RGBA here.
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, pixels.width, pixels.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels.data);

    // Ready to draw!
  });
```

Hopefully this is of use to someone in the future. Thanks to everyone who contributed thoughts and ideas, and thanks to the collaborators on jpeg-js!

Comment: Glad you figured this out, but man, I wish there weren't so many hoops you had to jump through.

Answer (score 1):

From the search through Chromium codebase for the error message string and looking at `revokeObjectURL` reference it seems that it is the culprit. The image content represented by image URL simply gets "freed" to early. The solution would be to call `revokeObjectURL` *after* calling `texImage2D`.

Comment: For the sake of testing, I removed the line that revokes the object url entirely - but the error did not change. Thanks, though.

Comment: Thats unfortunate. I've noticed that you're creating URL object not with the blob but with some `data`. Can you elaborate in the question how do get it from the blob (because passing a blob works fine for me)?

Comment: That was a typo - fixed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Are your 100% sure that an image is recieved in fetch? Is it from same origin as the page? Or are CORS headers set up correctly? I can't reproduce the problem with the information you've gave: http://jsbin.com/puferisera/edit?js,output (or I'm missing something).

Comment: Yep, 100% sure.  I got it working after a while. Take a look at the answer I posted for details. Thanks for your help!